# React Native, unable to get access token

Tags: reactjs, azure, react-native, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using react-native-app-auth to get access token from azure ad b2c but I'm facing issues in android and in IOS
in android it's showing error that
`Unable to complete authorization as there is no interactive call in progress. This can be due to closing the app while the authorization was in process.`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2Fft.png

and in IOS it's redirecting but not returning anything.

that's my code

```
const config = {
  issuer:
    'https://ksg1806.b2clogin.com/tenantId/v2.0/',
  clientId: 'clientId',
  redirectUrl:
    Platform.OS == 'ios'
      ? 'msauth.com.gfk.consumervoice://auth'
      : 'msauth://com.gfkconsumer/Cb7s2L1nogp57%2BKdddohtF8%2Funk%3D',
  additionalParameters: {},
  scopes: ['openid'],
  serviceConfiguration: {
    authorizationEndpoint:
      'https://ksg1806.b2clogin.com/ksg1806.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_signup_signin/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
    tokenEndpoint:
      'https://gfkms.b2clogin.com/GFKMS.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_signup_signin/oauth2/v2.0/token',
    revocationEndpoint:
      'https://gfkms.b2clogin.com/GFKMS.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_signup_signin/oauth2/v2.0/logout',
  },
};

  const getAccessToken = async () => {
    try {
      const authState = await authorize(config);
      console.log(authState);
    } catch (error: any) {
      Alert.alert('Failed to log in', error.message);
    }
  };
```

if anyone know about that please help I'm stuck here for many days

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below points can narrow down the issue:

1. For v2 endpoint scope acts as resource   . If the resource identifier
   is omitted in the scope parameter, the resource is assumed to be
   Microsoft Graph.  If token is for Microsoft graph try by changing or
   adding  scope  :  User.Read  . For example, scope=User.Read is
   equivalent to https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read  and
   offline_access is for refresh tokens  Or try to Add the scope to
   existing openid scope like scopes: []

For example:
`scopes: ['openid', 'profile', email,'offline_access'],` (or) `scopes: ['openid', 'profile','offline_access']`

> Optional:Try also by giving client_secret inside the config

2. Make sure you have set the redirect url correctly.Add a trailing slash to redirect url to your config - e.g. msauth.BUNDLEID://auth/ - failure to add that may cause it to fail in IOS.
3. The cause may also be due to the user cancelling the operation in the middle of the process before authentication is completed.See  [Troubleshooting  B2C | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot?pivots=b2c-user-flow#user-canceled-the-operation)

**References:**

1. [AppAuth iOS Token Exchange Problems Azure AD - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46162183/appauth-ios-token-exchange-problems-azure-ad)
2. [Microsoft identity platform scopes, permissions, & consent | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#example-2-the-user-hasnt-granted-permissions-between-the-client-and-the-resource)
3. [react-native-app-auth (github.com)](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth#register-redirect-url-scheme)